# Rider 2019.1.3 "cannot resolve View" when path is in subfolder

Tags: c#, .net-core, jetbrains-ide, nopcommerce, rider

I notice there was a question with a very similar title, however, it was asked 9 years ago and not about Rider.

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, this is the original clone of [nopcommerce](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce)

the view exists as shown on the left(highlighted file) but rider says cannot "cannot resolve view xxx". The project can be successfully built.

Any idea on this? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you use `return View("Configure", model);` instead?

Comment: Please check into csproj file.
`<Content Include="Views\Configure.cshtml">      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>`

Comment: @mjwills Same, Cannot resolve view 'Configure'

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara `<Content Include="Views\Configure.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>` Yes, this is already in .csproj

Comment: Have you tried to run your project? and get an run time error?

Comment: Check the output folder of the view.If it not there then right click on the view and make copy always or newest.

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara There is neither build nor run time error

Comment: @sina_Islam The file is in the output folder and can run correctly.. It is the IDE's fault...

Comment: @MiDaa Which IDE you are using.

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara JetBrains Rider as mentioned in the title...